# Can someone help me interpret the if statement in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

```
function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i])) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

I'm confused by the syntax. Typically what I've seen so far is

```
if (condition) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

where condition is some boolean statement which will run the code shown if condition = true.

But, in this if statement, there is no boolean, nor is there code to be executed after the conditonal statement. I have no clue what it means. Thanks in advance for any help interpeting it.

Comment: We have no way to tell what `callback(array[i])` evaluates as since you haven't shown us that function. What makes you think it isn't a boolean? (`if` doesn't care if something is a boolean or not though, only if it is truthy or falsy).

Comment: You need to include the actual `callback` function that is passed into the `filterArray` function for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

`(callback(array[i]))` this part is the condition. `newArray.push(array[i])` this is what happens when the condition is met. It just looks so close together.

```js
if (callback(array[i])) 
{
   newArray.push(array[i])
}
```

Does same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a boolean, namely the value returned from calling the function `callback` with argument `array[i]`. (To be precise: The interpretation of the returned value as a truth value according to the JavaScript language specs - this is what is meant by 'truthy' or 'falsy'. For starters just assume that `callback` does indeed return a boolean value)

There also is code being executed: The first statement after the condition.
This is just a notational shorthand. The verbose equivalent code would be:

```
if (callback(array[i])) {
    newArray.push(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (callback(array[i])) newArray.push(array[i]);` simply means that `callback` is a function, that gets called and a return value is expected (could be any value, not only boolean). Then, if the return is **truthy**, the statement `newArray.push(array[i]);` gets executed.

(A single line `if (exp) statement;` can be written like this, but may sometimes hide bugs, so some linters prefer to always change it to

```
if (exp) {
  statement;
}
```

Callbacks are typically functions that get passed in as an argument (exactly as you see here) that then may get called.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition isn't working try to use a if else loop. If your statement isn't what you expect show an error message, else push array[i];

```
function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (!callback(array[i])){
       console.log('Something went wrong');
  }else{
       newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  return newArray;
}
´´´

Since you only give this piece of code, it's hard to analyze it, but this may work
```